# What is the 4269 or 4326 in sql GeometryFromText('POINT(lat lon)',4269)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Somebody please tell me clearly what does the value 4269 or 4326 mean in sql function **GeometryFromText('POINT(lat lon)',4269)**, I have checked it in google but couldn't clear description.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the [Spatial Reference System Identifier (SRID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID), basicly it is the coordinate system you are using for the numbers you are entering for `lat` and `lon`.

Here is the page for the specification for [4269](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/) and [4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)

Answer (score 1):

If you search the documentation of this function (link below), you'll see this number is the coordinateSystemId, i.e., an integer number telling the function which coordinate system you are using.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823(v=sql.110).aspx

I believe you may find a table where you can pick the exact meaning of this particular number.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is for the C# wrapper method for when you are using stuff like Entity Framework, if you are going to just point them at documentation, at least point them at [the correct documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933823.aspx).